# How to remove annoying photo from skype desktop?

Tags: skype

I always see unknown girl photo in my Windows version `Skype` in its "desktop" with caption:

> How to make free voice and video calls

[image]

I don't know this person and I'm slightly tired see her face in my Skype. Is any way totally remove it from Skype?

Comment: Click VIEW in the menu.
Then click SPLIT WINDOW VIEW.
Then click SINGLE WINDOW VIEW.   this is temporary Im going to play around with my skype when i get home to try and see if there is a certain code that can block this out.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Wow, that's the trick, it works! This should be an answer!

Comment: its the answer now.

Comment: New company uses skype for comm. It had me wondering why was everyone talking to this girl all the time, I even asked my colleague why he is chatting with her all the time....awkward~ Well done MS Skype, if i didn't know u better if would think it is the best UX troll.

Comment: Don't you find the woman aesthetically pleasing to look at? I think she's sexy. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click VIEW in the menu. 
Then click SPLIT WINDOW VIEW. 
Then click SINGLE WINDOW VIEW

I will dig deeper into this later and give it a better more in depth answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your Skype
2. Go to **Tools > Change Language**
3. At bottom - Click **Edit Skype Language File...**
4. **Language file editor** will show up - click on Save as - then save it somewhere.
5. Back to **Tools > Change Language**
6. At bottom - **Click Load Skype language file...**
7. Select the language file you saved before and click **Open**.
8. Restart Skype

Answer (score 2):

In Skype open Tools -> Change language. At the bottom of the language list select the option: Edit Skype Language File. The Language Editor window will pop-up. Click now on the Save as button and save the language file with a name of your choice. Open again Tools -> Change language and load this user defined language file.

You will not see any "instructional messages" anymore.